# Symbols inside Arrays (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays, assert, symbols

I'm doing some koans exercises and am having trouble understanding the values returned with symbols inside arrays. Can someone explain why the following are equal or suggest a good article on the subject that I could infer the proper knowledge from??? This is different than with strings:

```
    array = [:peanut, :butter, :and, :jelly]

     assert_equal [:and, :jelly], array[2,2]
     assert_equal [:and, :jelly], array[2,20]
     assert_equal [:jelly, :peanut], array[4,0]
     assert_equal [:jelly, :jelly], array[4,100]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, the last two evaluate to 0 to be true, please disregard the first array on the left of the comma! Also why is this true: assert_equal nil, array[5, 0]?

Comment: Are you asking how array[2,2], etc. work, or are you asking how equality works in Ruby?

Comment: @ Michael How array[2, 2] works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out now and always [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D): `ary[start, length] → new_ary or nil`.

It returns subarray. Here 'start' is the index of first element in you array, `length` stands for length of subarray. If `length >= ary.size - start` you will get subarray from `start` to end of ary.

In your case:

```
array = [:peanut, :butter, :and, :jelly]   
array[2, 2] #=>  [:and, jelly]
array[2,20] #=>  [:and, jelly]
array[4, 0] #=> []; length of empty array is 0!
array[4, 100] #=> []; well, okay. There's no element with index equal to 4.
             # but holy documentation says "empty array is returned when 
             # the starting index for an element range is at the end of 
             # the array."
array[5, 0]  #=> nil; there's nothing at 5th position.
array[-2, 2] #=> [:and, jelly]; :)
```

You told that strings inside arrays act not like this? You must be facing black magic. May you provide me an example?

Comment: I misunderstood the following: array[start_index, length]. Thanks for the info, your explanations were very clear.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are looking at the results from the wrong angle. What is being asserted here is the slicing of the array. If you slice an array like

```
array[start_index, length]
```

It means that you are getting a sub-array starting from a specific index with a specific length. That way your examples make sense.

It doesn't actually matter what kind of elements are in the array.

See [the array#slice documentation of Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Also look at the `values_at` method:

```
array = [:peanut, :butter, :and, :jelly]
p array.values_at(2,0) #=> [:and, :peanut]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lowercase `%i` stands for

> Non-interpolated Array of symbols, separated by whitespace (after Ruby 2.0)

In addition, uppercase `%I` means

> Interpolated Array of symbols, separated by whitespace (after Ruby
>   2.0)

```
a = 2

%i{one two #{a}+three} # Interpolation is ignored

 => [:one, :two, :"\#{a}+three"]

%I{one two #{a}+three} # Interpolation works

 => [:one, :two, :"1+three"]
```

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals

```
%i{one two three} # after Ruby 2.0 => [:one, :two, :three]
```